# Enviar peticiones http desde swift a servidor laravel

Tags: laravel, ios, swift

estoy desarrollando una aplicación para iOS en la que necesito obtener información del servidor, para eso utilizo peticiones http a un servidor ec2 con laravel.

En mi servidor tengo una ruta en la que sólo regreso un arreglo:

```
Route::post('/obtenerdatos', function () {
   return json_encode(array("status" => 2, "ID" => 1));
});
```

Pero siempre obtengo una página de error 419 "Page Expired"

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: tienes la ruta en web.php o en api.php?

Comment: la tengo en web.php

Comment: Las rutas en web.php tienen aplicado un middleware de protección contra los ataques de falsificación de solicitudes entre sitios (CSRF). Si no quieres lidiar con eso, y no tienes ningún motivo en especial para que la ruta esté en web.php, puedes ponerla en api.php. Pero depende de lo que quieras hacer... Tampoco sé por que el método es post, si solo devuelve un arreglo. Tal vez si explicas un poco más lo que quieres lograr, alguien te puede sugerir cuales son las opciones para conseguirlo.

Comment: Seria bueno que muestres la solicitud que envias, no solo la ruta, ya que el problema es que no envias el `_token`

Answer (score 0):

Tu aplicación no está enviando el token CSRF en la solicitud y la ruta está bajo el grupo web middlware que aplica el middleware `VerifyCsrfToken`. Ver [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf) en la documentación.

Puedes mover la ruta a `api.php` o agregarla como excepción en el middleware:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'obtenerdatos'
    ];
}
```